# Update query Php Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Почему не хочет изменять изменения в базе данных, где ошибка?

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

```
  <tr>

      <th>User Id</th>
      <th>User Name</th>
      <th>User E-mail</th>
      <th>User Pass</th>
      <th>Delete User</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <?php
  include("../registration/database/db_conection.php");
  $view_users_query="select * from users";//select query for viewing users.
  $run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$view_users_query);//here run the sql query.

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))//while look to fetch the result and store in a array $row.
  {
      $user_id=$row[0];
      $user_name=$row[1];
      $user_pass=$row[2];
      $user_email=$row[3];
  ?>       
  <tr>

      <td><input type="text" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="user_name" value="<?php echo $user_name; ?>"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="user_email" value="<?php echo $user_email; ?>"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="user_pass" value="<?php echo $user_pass; ?>"></td>
      <td><a href="delete.php?del=<?php echo $user_id ?>"><button class="btn btn- danger">Delete</button></a></td> <!--btn btn-danger is a bootstrap button to show danger-->
      <td><button type="submit" name="update" class="btn">Update</button></td>
  </tr>

  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: У вас одна форма на всю таблицу из N строк?

Comment: и где код изменения БД? приведен только вывод.

Comment: добавил, ниже,б

Comment: @Brandabul, вы можете изменять свой вопрос. Ниже вопроса мелки шрифтом `править`.